# How can I exchange ids with names in comma data in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I have a table like below which has names and ids.

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Robb |
| 2 | Sansa |
| 3 | Arya |
| 4 | Bran |
| 5 | Rickon |
| 6 | Cersei |
| 7 | Jaime |
| 8 | Tyrion |

And there is another table like below

| Family Name | brothers | sisters |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Stark | 1,4,5 | 2,3 |
| Lennister | 7,8 | 6 |

I need a query which will give brothers' name for stark family in one row with separate by comma

| Family Name | brothers | sisters |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Stark | Robb,Bran,Rickon | Sansa,Arya |

Thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use correlated sub-queries and check whether the `id` column is a substring of the `brothers` or `sisters` and then use `LISTAGG` to aggregate the matched names.

Assuming that you want the `name` to be in the same order as the `id` are in the `brothers` or `sisters` lists then you could use:

```sql
SELECT family_name,
       (
          SELECT LISTAGG(b.name, ',')
                   WITHIN GROUP (
                     ORDER BY INSTR(','||f.brothers||',', ','||b.id||',')
                   )
          FROM   people b
          WHERE  INSTR(','||f.brothers||',', ','||b.id||',') > 0
       ) AS brothers,
       (
          SELECT LISTAGG(s.name, ',')
                   WITHIN GROUP (
                     ORDER BY INSTR(','||f.sisters||',', ','||s.id||',')
                   )
          FROM   people s
          WHERE  INSTR(','||f.sisters||',', ','||s.id||',') > 0
       ) AS sisters
FROM   families f
```

However, if you want the `name` to be sorted by `id` value then you could use:

```sql
SELECT family_name,
       (
          SELECT LISTAGG(b.name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY b.id)
          FROM   people b
          WHERE  ','||f.brothers||',' LIKE '%,'||b.id||',%'
       ) AS brothers,
       (
          SELECT LISTAGG(s.name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY s.id)
          FROM   people s
          WHERE  ','||f.sisters||',' LIKE '%,'||s.id||',%'
       ) AS sisters
FROM   families f
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE people (ID, Name) AS
SELECT 1, 'Robb' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Sansa' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Arya' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Bran' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Rickon' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Cersei' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'Jaime' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'Tyrion' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE families (Family_Name, brothers, sisters ) AS
SELECT 'Stark', '1,4,5', '2,3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Lannister', '7,8', '6' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | FAMILY_NAME | BROTHERS | SISTERS |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Stark | Robb,Bran,Rickon | Sansa,Arya |
> | Lannister | Jaime,Tyrion | Cersei |

If you just want the `Stark` row then add a filter condition as the final line to either query:

```sql
WHERE  family_name = 'Stark'
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=15d226eda5f7ed12852509e48e5ccceb)*

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what im looking for